# What is git's default merge tool? Can I use it with TortoiseHg?

Tags: git, merge, tortoise-hg

My coworker wants to switch to Git because she says Mercurial has trouble with some simple merges. When I do a merge on the hg command line, I see the output

```
couldn't find merge tool codecompare_diff
couldn't find merge tool codecompare_merge
couldn't find merge tool bcompare
...
couldn't find merge tool meld
couldn't find merge tool diffuse
```

I'm not sure which one TortoiseHg actually uses in the end, but to me this says that I could plug in a different one and possibly duplicate the merging behavior of Git, like

```
[merge-tools]
 mymergetool.something = something
```

However, any docs I found for git mergetool listed which tools were [supported](https://gist.github.com/karenyyng/f19ff75c60f18b4b8149), but not which one was actually responsible for git's default merge behavior.

Comment: Git (at least on windows) is distributed with the option to install KDiff3. they make it clear that this is an optional external dependency that you could fill in other ways, but thats the one they ship. Image of installer dialog here: http://git-extensions-documentation.readthedocs.io/en/latest/_images/install2.png

Answer (score 4):

The default merge tool in git is *mergetool*, you can configure it by using:

```
git config --global merge.tool "mergetool"
```

Check the link for doubts:
https://www.git-scm.com/docs/git-mergetool

Comment: I would say that is the *command to set* a default mergetool, but this is still a very helpful answer with that link. 

The link says *If a merge resolution program is not specified, git mergetool will use the configuration variable merge.tool. If the configuration variable merge.tool is not set, git mergetool will pick a suitable default.* Can you tell what the suitable default is in your install or what the default setting for merge.tool is? I don't have git on my system, I am trying to make Hg behave like git.

Comment: To check to which tools may merge be set to you can execute: 

    *git mergetool --tool-help*

I hope that can help you.